# Grounding wire attached to ceiling lamp but canopy of light fixture not grounded, is this serious problem?

Tags: ceiling, grounding, light, metal

I've just installed a new metal pendant light. The light itself has a metal canopy and there is a metal bulb holder below, the two parts are connected via insulated wire. The light came with a grounding wire which I have connected with the grounding wire from the ceiling, so I am confident that the bottom part of the light (ie where you change the bulb is grounded). Now, having thought of it though, the metal casing (canopy?) above is not grounded itself. It acts simply as a means of holding up the lamp and covering the wiring... nothing is connected to it other than the insulated wires feeding down to the light. Obviously, the wires are not touching it directly, but there are quite a few wires connected inside this canopy. If over time, a wire came loose, potentially there could be a wire which touch that metal canopy. No one will be climbing on chairs to touch this, so I am not as concerned about electric shock, but more so would this be considered faulty wiring? As I said, we connected the ground wires of the lamp to the ceiling, but seems to be a bit of a bad design where is metal canopy itself wasn't taken into consideration. Is it a fire hazard? Really can't afford an electrician at this point and didn't plan on doing so as I've wired lights before. Fairly confident the wiring is correct and secure, but I'm a worrier.

Comment: Is the canopy making metal-to-metal contact with some other grounded part, such as the outer bulb holder shell or the fixture mounting brackets?

Comment: No, that's the problem. It only comes into contact with plastic parts or insulated wire.

Comment: Any chance of getting a picture of that?

Comment: What's the provenance of the fixture? Does it have a UL marking? Was it sourced from Amazon Marketplace?